# Why can I run command, but not using sudo?

Tags: sudo, rails

I log as user named `rails` and can `searchd --config /etc/abc.xyz/sphinx.conf`.

When I do `sudo -u rails searchd --config /etc/abc.xyz/sphinx.conf`, it returns:

> Sorry, user rails is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/searchd --config /etc/abc.xyz/sphinx.conf' as rails on abc.xyz.

How can I use `sudo`? I need it for Capistrano deploy.

Comment: Maybe something gets configured when you do a real login? Try `sudo -u rails -i searchd  --config /etc/abc.xyz/sphinx.conf` as this runs your command in a login shell of the specified user, which causes it to e.g. run all the login scripts for that user first. Does that work?

Comment: “*When I do `sudo -u rails ...`*” You execute it as user `rails`, or using another account?

Comment: I mean user rails

Comment: `Unlike indexer, searchd is not designed to be run either from a regular script or command-line calling, but instead either as a daemon to be called from init.d (on Unix/Linux type systems) or to be called as a service (on Windows-type systems), so not all of the command line options will always apply, and so will be build-dependent.` from the [Sphinx page](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/ref-searchd.html) .. maybe loged in as rails you may start the deamon from shell but not from passing it through sudo?

Comment: Does your own invoking user have a sudoers entry? Any of the groups of your user? If so, what are they?

Answer (score 1):

I think the Problem is in the permissions of the file `/etc/abc.xyz/Sphinx.config`:

I guess you have set permissions for the user rails but when you call

```
sudo -u rails searchd --config /etc/abc.xyz/sphinx.conf
```

As far as I know you only call the command `searchd --config` as user rails while the user from which you call it might not have access permissions to the file `/etc/abc.xyz/sphinx.config`.

so giving the sudo user permissions on this file should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Add user to sudo.

```
adduser rails sudo
```

Comment: This is not correct. Only the user that invokes `sudo` must be in that group, not the target user as which `sudo` will run the command.

Comment: @ByteCommander right, it is not god way to give sudo permissions for user.